# Iconos de archivos no se muestran correctamente

Tags: vscode

Lo que me pasa es que en los videos que he visto cuando crean el archivo con la extencion .css, les aparece el logo de CSS, que es un 3 creo, a mi cuando creo el archivo y lo abro en VSC me aparece un #, dejo la foto arriba, escribo codigo, pero no cambia en nada cuando guardo y entro al navegador, alguien me ayudaria?(arriba donde dice index.html, estilo.css, index.js, ahi es donde aparece el # y no el logo de CSS) Muchisimas Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es una extensión que debes instalar. Busca `icons` entre las extensiones e instala la que más te guste. Por ejemplo esta: [`vscode-icons`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons)

Comment: Si no cambia nada, imagino que es porque no lo enlazaste en tu html. En cuanto al icono, es lo que dice Mauricio, VSC por defecto no trae mucha personalización, pero tiene muchísimos plugins

Comment: muchicimas gracias a los dos :D

Comment: @MauricioContreras pon eso como respuesta

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro hecho. Aunque algo tarde. XD

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Tal como digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/502894/iconos-de-archivos-no-se-muestran-correctamente?noredirect=1#comment893710_502894):

Es una extensión que debes instalar. Busca `icons` entre las extensiones e instala la que más te guste. Por ejemplo esta: [vscode-icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons)

Adjunto captura de imagen que muestra dónde ver las extensiones y el resultado de la búsqueda de la palabra `icons`:

[image: Captura de las extensiones de VSCode buscando icons]